# File Download doesn't work with $.get or $.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller method set up for file download, and it works (user is prompted to open/save file) if the method is called directly using a hyperlink. However, if I chose to explicitly call the method by doing an explicit get request, I don't get the prompt for the file download, although the action method is successfully called.

```
    $("#id").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var postdata = { filename: $("#filename").text() };
        $.get("/Test/Fix", postdata);
    });
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Or is this by design?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `window.location='your desired server action path with proper parameters';`

so the final code will look like:

```
$("#id").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filename = $("#filename").text();
        window.location= "/Test/Fix?filename="+filename;
    });
```

Hope this will help :)